# How save the number of logins to the application ?(nodejs,JS,mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I use in my project mongodb database with nodejs and javascript.
I wonder how can I save number of logins to my application to e.g database table.
(After successful login to application, by insert an email and password).
I use (passport authentication with nodejs).

Can you lead me somehow ?

Best regards

Comment: This question needs more focus! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) again to find out what kind of questions Stack Overflow [is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) intended for. Please ask questions relating to one specific programming issue, providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a key named as a loginCount into your MongoDB collection for every user such that whenever a user logged in successfully into your application than before providing token to them you can just hit the query for updating this count by using increment function of MongoDB.